# Unable to switch screens using kivy language

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am new to Kivy language. I am trying build a simple program to switch between two screens. First screen with contain a button which on_release it will switch to second screen. On clicking the button on second screen will get to first screen.

Issues i face:
 1. Button is placed on the corner and i am expecting its size to be full window but it small

2. On click and release the button doesnt' show any effect.

## Chat.kv

```
<ChatGUI>:
    MainManager:
        MainWindow:
        SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        text:"to second window"
        on_release:app.root.current="second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text:"back to main"
        on_release:app.root.current="main"
```

## python code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Canvas
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder

class ChatGUI(Widget):
    present=Builder.load_file("Chat.kv")
class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass
class MainManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class ChatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChatGUI()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```

## My output#  i am not able to add image so posted link of output

[image]

I am practicing from youtube tutorial.

I have checked many codes from stack overflow and i don't see issues in my code.

output should display button of size occupying whole window and on_release it should switch to next screen.

Can you let me know what could be issue.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add a `ScreenManager` inside a `Widget`.
So

```
class ChatGUI (ScreenManager):
```

in python file and

```
<ChatGUI>:
     MainWindow:
     SecondWindow:
```

in kv file
that's all I changed to make your example work.

Chat.kv

```
<ChatGUI>:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        text:"to second window"
        on_release:app.root.current="second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text:"back to main"
        on_release:app.root.current="main"
```

main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color, Canvas
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.lang import Builder

class ChatGUI(ScreenManager):
    present=Builder.load_file("Chat.kv")

class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass
class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass

class ChatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChatGUI()

if __name__=="__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

## Problem 1 - widget @ bottom left hand corner & not full window?

> Button is placed on the corner and i am expecting its size to be full
>   window but it small

### Root Cause

1. The Button widget appeared on the bottom left hand corner because the root is a [Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html) and no position ([pos](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos), or [pos_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.pos_hint)) was provided. Therefore, the default position of (0, 0) was used.
2. The [size](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size) is not a full window because by default the size of a [Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html) is (100 x 100) or the default [size_hint](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget.size_hint) is (1, 1).

#### [Kivy Widget » Default values](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html)

> - A [Widget](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.widget.html#kivy.uix.widget.Widget) is not a [Layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout): it will not change the position or the size of its children. If you want control over positioning or
>     sizing, use a [Layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout).
> - The default size of a widget is (100, 100). This is only changed if the parent is a [Layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html#kivy.uix.layout.Layout). For example, if you add a Label inside a
>     Button, the label will not inherit the button’s size or position
>     because the button is not a Layout: it’s just another Widget.
> - The default size_hint is (1, 1). If the parent is a Layout, then the widget size will be the parent layout’s size.

## Problem 2 - on release button screen not switched?

> On click and release the button doesnt' show any effect.

### Root Cause

The screen was not switched when button press was released, because the root of the App is not a [ScreenManager](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManager).

## Solution

There are two options to the problems.

### Option 1 - use Layout as root

This option use [BoxLayout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.boxlayout.html) as the root and requires the following enhancements. A [Layout](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.layout.html) can be a `GridLayout`, `BoxLayout`, `FloatLayout`, etc.

#### Py file

1. Replace Widget with BoxLayout
2. Replace `present = Builder.load_file(...)` with `Builder.load_file(...)`
3. Move `Builder.load_file(...)` out of `class ChatGUI()` and add `pass`

#### kv file

1. Add `id: sm` under instantiated object, `MainManager:`
2. Replace `app.root.current` with `app.root.ids.sm.current`

#### Snippets - Option 1

**main1.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_file("main1.kv")


class ChatGUI(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class MainManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ChatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChatGUI()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```

**main1.kv**

```
<ChatGUI>:
    MainManager:
        id: sm
        MainWindow:
        SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        text: "to second window"
        on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current="second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text: "back to main"
        on_release: app.root.ids.sm.current="main"
```

### Option 2 - use ScreenManager as root

This option requires the following enhancements:

#### Py file

1. Remove import statement, `from kivy.uix.widget import Widget`
2. Remove `class ChatGUI()`
3. Replace `return ChatGUI()` with `return MainManager()`
4. Replace `present = Builder.load_file(...)` with `Builder.load_file(...)`

#### kv file

1. Remove class rule, : in the kv file
2. Replace MainManager: with class rule, :

#### Snippets - Option 2

**main2.py**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder


Builder.load_file("main2.kv")


class MainWindow(Screen):
    pass


class SecondWindow(Screen):
    pass


class MainManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ChatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainManager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
```

**main2.kv**

```
<MainManager>:
    MainWindow:
    SecondWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    Button:
        text: "to second window"
        on_release: app.root.current="second"

<SecondWindow>:
    name: "second"
    Button:
        text: "back to main"
        on_release: app.root.current="main"
```

Comment: This provided knowledge along with solution. Thanks for that. 
But when i implemented first solution, it displays two buttons side by side occupying half of the window each. However, on_release is working. Can you let me know what is the issue? do i need to configure something for boxlayout ..to get only one button

#output#
 ![output](https://imgur.com/a/PtQlXvc)

Comment: I got the issue. I am loading .kv file explicitly and also by default. This is causing to load instance twice. It got resolved when i remove the explicit load_file(). Thanks all for your help

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

[If you accept someone else's answer: You gain +2 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)